# Would this be a valid way to implement pimpl that supports inheritance?

Tags: c++, pimpl-idiom

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <cstdlib>

class IBase
{
public:
    IBase() = default;
    virtual ~IBase() = default;
    virtual void f1() = 0;
};

class IDerived
{
public:
    IDerived() = default;
    virtual ~IDerived() = default;
    virtual void f2() = 0;
};

class BaseImpl : public IBase
{
public:
    BaseImpl() = default;
    virtual ~BaseImpl() override = default;
    virtual void f1() override { /* serious code */}
};

class DerivedImpl : public BaseImpl, public IDerived
{
public:
    DerivedImpl() = default;
    virtual ~DerivedImpl() override = default;
    virtual void f2() override { /* serious code */}
};

class Base : public IBase
{
public:
    Base() : m_impl(std::make_shared<BaseImpl>()) {}
    virtual ~Base() override = default;
    virtual void f1() override { m_impl->f1(); }

protected:
    Base(const std::shared_ptr<BaseImpl>& impl) : m_impl(impl) {}
    std::shared_ptr<BaseImpl> m_impl;
};

class Derived : public Base, public IDerived
{
public:
    Derived() : Base(std::make_shared<DerivedImpl>()) {}
    virtual ~Derived() override = default;
    virtual void f2() override { impl()->f2(); }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<DerivedImpl> impl() { return std::dynamic_pointer_cast<DerivedImpl>(m_impl); }
};

int main()
{
    Base base;
    base.f1();

    Derived derived;
    derived.f1();
    derived.f2();

    std::cin.sync();
    std::cin.get();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

It works, but it looks so weird that I might just give up pimpl.

Comment: Best ask yourfelf, Why should I implement the pimpl idiom?

Comment: @Claudiordgz, pointless question. The idiom reduces coupling between translation units. Not real one, but artificial coupling due to the way the language handles inclusion.

Comment: @NFRCR I don't feel that is pointless. Because based on what you are saying, his implementation still lacks further development to add that artificial coupling. Asking why keeps you focused on an objective on implementing something. I know the reasons to implement pimpl, which this does not seem to take me there.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine having your Base defined like this:

```
class Base {
public:
    Base();
    virtual ~Base();
    virtual void f1();

protected:
    class Impl;
    Impl *p_impl; // or shared_ptr, or unique_ptr, or whatever you like.
};
```

Note that there is nothing defined of `Base::Impl`. This is a very important part of the PIMPL idiom as you might have to use elements in the Impl class that require `#include`-ing things you don't want to include in the header class.

The derived class would then look like this:

```
class Derived: public Base {
public:
    Derived();
    ~Derived();
    virtual void f1(); // or not, depends
    virtual void f2();

protected:
    class Impl2;
    Impl2 *p_impl2; // note that Derived::Impl2 might inherit from Base::Impl
};
```

This still hides the implementation details of both `Base` and `Derived` in `Base::Impl` and `Derived::Impl2`, while giving you complete freedom to implement `Derived` in any way you like (including inheritance).

Comment: But isn't it really strange to have the class 'Derived' also contain p_impl while it already contains p_impl2? Also it would be necessary to make p_impl == p_impl2, it would be crazy if there would be instances of Impl and Impl2 both instantiated for Derived.

Comment: @NFRCR It depends on your Impl implementation really. You could have p_impl == p_impl2, but that would give you two downsides for only a few bytes saved: 1) You would expose that fact in your header file, which is a big deal, and 2) you would have to cast in your Derived implementation all the time. It's not crazy to have seperate implementations, don't forget that Impl is fully available to Derived and it could just amend the implementation with Impl2.

Comment: @NFRCR Sorry, I meant you could have only one pointer instead of having p_impl == p_impl2...

Answer (score 1):

Your `Impl` classes should only contain private variables and methods.

Don't put anything that that need to be accessible from children class there. Sub-classing the `Impl` class is wrong way to go in C++ because that defeats the purpose of this pattern.

Comment: It does not defeat the purpose of this pattern. I wish to design a library that in its header files (exported to the end user) does not hint anything about the underlying implementation. The classes of the implementation itself are very much allowed to be able to 'peek' at others.

Comment: Then it's the Bridge Pattern that you're talking about, not the C++ PIMPL idiom. Go look it up.